# Solving systems of equations graphically

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, quadratics

> $$y=(x-2)^2+4$$
>
> $$2x+y=7$$

I'm not quite sure how I would graph these. Just a line or parabola? And how would I tell?

Would I expand the first equation or use $2$ and $4$ to get the points?

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first is a parabola, the second a line. Just evaluate both on some range (for example $-5$ to $5$ with step $0.5$) and check whether they have common points.

Comment: So for the parabola, the vertex would be (2,4)?

Comment: You mean the minimum point ? Yes. And for the second equation , set $f(x)=-2x+7$

Comment: So, the points for the second equation would be (3.5, 7)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Draw the parabola (the first equation). Reduce to canonical form, you'll find that the minimum is reached at point $(2,4)$. It crosses $y$-axis at $(0,8)$.

**2)** Draw line (the second equation). It crosses $y$-axis at $(0,7)$ and $x$-axis at $\left(\frac72,0\right)$.

**3)** Find their intersection point(s):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Draw the parabola $y=(x-2)^2+4$ and the line $y=-2x+7$ and find common points.

Answer (score 0):

prove that $y=-2x+7$ is a Tangent line to the given parabola

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In simple cases 
the solution can be clearly seen. 
Like in this plot, the lines have 
one common point at $(1,5)$,
which is also easy to check.